# List Client Side Printers

Tags: c#

How to list a client side printer in asp.net using c#?

My code: This will list the printers connected to the server.

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\root\cimv2");
scope.Connect();
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer");
foreach (ManagementObject printer in searcher.Get())
{
    string printerName = printer["Name"].ToString().ToLower();
    Response.Write("chethann            ");
    Response.Write(printerName);
}
```

Comment: You can only list the printers through C#, for the machine the code is executed on. Are you trying this in a ASP.NET application? Then you only see the server printers. If you are trying this in a forms application, then you only see the printers of the machine the application runs

Answer (score 0):

```
PrinterInformation info = new PrinterInformation();
var printers = info.GetPrinters();
foreach (var printer in printers)
{
Response.Write(string.Format("Machine Name : {0} - Printer Name: {1}", Environment.MachineName, printer.DeviceName));
}
```

Comment: I am not able to create PrinterInformation object. Can u please help me in creating PrinterInformation object.

Comment: @Chethan: Don't suggest edits that add a comment to a answer. Use this "comments" section, instead.